# Change cursor shape (or color) to indicate vi mode in bash

Tags: bash, vi, line-editor

**To clarify:** I am not asking how to [change the cursor when using vim within a terminal](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Configuring_the_cursor). I want the cursor to change when switching between input and command mode within Bash's vi-mode:

```
set -o vi <CR> type some text <ESC> (the cursor changes shape/color)
i (cursor change back) etc...
```

I found [a script](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=95078) that makes changing color of the cursor on mode changes possible in **zsh**, but I don't want to change shells just for this one feature.

Is there a way to get the cursor to change shape, like in gvim, (or even just color) when switching between command and insert modes on the Bash command line?

Comment: Same question in SO for Putty, no answer tho :( -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393383/how-to-let-putty-change-its-cursor-shape-accordingly

Answer (score 10):

add these two lines to **~/.inputrc** :

```
set vi-ins-mode-string \1\e[5 q\2
set vi-cmd-mode-string \1\e[2 q\2
```

Comment: This answer would be much more useful if you explain what they do and provide some context, e.g, do the settings require the user to have a particular version of Readline.

Comment: :) here is the manual entry : https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Readline-Init-File-Syntax.html#index-vi_002dcmd_002dmode_002dstring

Comment: This will only work on terminals and terminal emulators that understand DECSCUSR.

Comment: I had to add `set show-mode-in-prompt on` in `~/.inputrc` also to make this work.

Comment: Okay, so `\1` and `\2` are to begin and end the escape sequence. `\e[5` and `\e[2` to set the cursor mode (blinking bar and steady block in this case). But what does the `q` do?

Answer (score 5):

Copied from here - [Command-line editing vim style](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116369/command-line-editing-vim-style/116385)

Should be available in `bash` 4.3 - see the [changelog](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/plain/CHANGES-4.3?h=devel&id=c51b384fc790ec1c76f67238f3167bcdba9eb34d) -

```
j.  New user-settable variable, show-mode-in-prompt, adds a characters to the
    beginning of the prompt indicating the current editing mode.
```

`bash` 4.3 is currently at the `rc` stage, you should be able to get packages for most distros without compiling from source, though not in the main repositories. Eg. Ubuntu (amd64) [here](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/test/+build/5389244) and Debian (experimental repo) [here](https://packages.debian.org/experimental/bash).

Comment: Note that: the prompt will not be updated if you use a custom PS1 which contains a newline character.
found [here](https://gist.github.com/ethagnawl/86a0284c990196ae31b7)

Comment: @pgericson It seems to work with a custom PS1 containing a newline for me on bash 4.4.12.

Answer (score 3):

I've not find a real solution, but perhaps this could help you (or someone else) to find a better one.

You have to create a script (e.g. kmtest.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash
# Script "kmtest.sh"

TEST=`bind -v | awk '/keymap/ {print $NF}'`
if [ "$TEST" = 'vi-insert' ]; then
   echo -ne "\033]12;Green\007"
else
   echo -ne "\033]12;Red\007"
fi
```

and after add it to your PS1, something like:

```
export PS1="\u@\h \$(kmtest.sh)> "
```

but as I said, it is not what you want, cause it changes cursor color only after a cr. Good luck

gb

Comment: Did this actually work for you?  It did not work for me; it just made the cursor red.  I don't think kmtest.sh is run every time I switch between insert and command modes.  It seems like it would only be run on the creation of the prompt.

Answer (score 2):

While it's not exactly what you want (dynamically changing the cursor), bash 4.4 / readline 7.0 [will add support for dynamically changing the prompt](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/NEWS?h=96f66efe6fccbd914d3c92a45405af9a7cf25704#n108) . You will be able to specify custom mode indicators for insert/command modes (This is different then the current `show-mode-in-prompt` option which is hardcoded to use `+` and `:`).

Unfortunately these versions are currently in beta and don't seem to have all the bugs ironed out yet.  They're also missing the ability to specify where in the prompt you'd like the mode indicator to occur.

In the interim I've published patched versions of bash 4.3 / readline 6.3 on [github](https://github.com/calid/bash) with this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there may be a way to do it through hacking readline. Perhaps we could push for it to get mainstreamed?

Here is my answer on SO https://stackoverflow.com/a/12201092/255961 which I will update if I get more info.

Answer (score -1):

I asked the same question a while back on [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42663/how-to-make-cursor-change-from-thin-line-to-block-based-on-normal-or-insert-mode) when I was transitioning from Gvim to Console Vim.

I received [one answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42663/how-to-make-cursor-change-from-thin-line-to-block-based-on-normal-or-insert-mode/42666#42666) but it involved toggling the gnome terminal settings, and these settings applied across terminals. Thus, it was possible for the gnome terminal cursor to be stuck in the wrong state at times.

I'm still interested in whether you get a satisfactory solution, but over time I've adjusted to the lack of mode state information in the cursor. Perhaps I just press escape more often (e.g., `esc` to ensure I'm in command-mode; `esc i` to ensure I'm in insert mode); perhaps I look at the state displayed at the bottom of the screen; perhaps I've just internalised the mode.

Comment: Just to clarify, you're question is **not** the same as mine.  You asked how to change the cursor within Vim on the console.  This is well documented on the [Vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Configuring_the_cursor).  I want to know how to do this in [Bash's vi-mode](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/bash-vi-editing-mode-cheat-sheet/).