# Command-line editing vim style

Tags: shell, terminal, vim

I recently discovered terminal's feature, you can set the keys `emacs` or `vi` style

I prefer the second. so if you do

```
set -o vi
```

You can use `k j l h` keys to navigate on the command line. And you can switch between 'Normal' and 'Insert' modes like in `vim`.

However there's no way to visually distinguish one mode from another, even cursor doesn't change. Which makes vi-style pretty much useless. Is there a way to make it truly `vim`-like?

Comment: You didn't say which shell you're using. If you're using bash, see [Change cursor shape (or color) to indicate vi mode in bash](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/22527). If you're using zsh, see [make my zsh prompt show mode in vi mode](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/547/make-my-zsh-prompt-show-mode-in-vi-mode).

Comment: @Gilles, completely missed that. There may be some confusion about what `Terminal` actually does - http://superuser.com/questions/144666/what-is-the-difference-between-shell-console-and-terminal

Comment: @Graeme [What is the exact difference between a 'terminal', a 'shell', a 'tty' and a 'console'?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4126/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-a-terminal-a-shell-a-tty-and-a-con)

Comment: @Gilles, only reason for not linking that one was that there is no mention of `bash` in the top answer...

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, this is not possible in Bash. But ZSH supports this. See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/547/make-my-zsh-prompt-show-mode-in-vi-mode).

Answer (score 3):

Should be available in `bash` 4.3 - see the [changelog](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/plain/CHANGES-4.3?h=devel&id=c51b384fc790ec1c76f67238f3167bcdba9eb34d) -

```
j.  New user-settable variable, show-mode-in-prompt, adds a characters to the
    beginning of the prompt indicating the current editing mode.
```

`bash` 4.3 is currently at the `rc` stage, you should be able to get packages for most distros without compiling from source, though not in the main repositories. Eg. Ubuntu (amd64) [here](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/test/+build/5389244) and Debian (experimental repo) [here](https://packages.debian.org/experimental/bash).