# Changing cursor style based on mode in both zsh and vim

Tags: vim, zsh, oh-my-zsh, caret-cursor

I use *[vi-mode](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/tree/master/plugins/vi-mode)* in *[oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh)* with the *[af-magic](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/themes/af-magic.zsh-theme) [theme](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/themes)*.

I want the cursor style to indicate whether I am in *normal mode* (block) or *insert mode* (beam), both in `zsh` and in `vim`.

This is what I have so far:

In my `~/.zshrc`:

```
    # vim mode config
    # ---------------

    # Activate vim mode.
    bindkey -v

    # Remove mode switching delay.
    KEYTIMEOUT=5

    # Change cursor shape for different vi modes.
    function zle-keymap-select {
      if [[ ${KEYMAP} == vicmd ]] ||
         [[ $1 = 'block' ]]; then
        echo -ne '\e[1 q'

      elif [[ ${KEYMAP} == main ]] ||
           [[ ${KEYMAP} == viins ]] ||
           [[ ${KEYMAP} = '' ]] ||
           [[ $1 = 'beam' ]]; then
        echo -ne '\e[5 q'
      fi
    }
    zle -N zle-keymap-select

    # Use beam shape cursor on startup.
    echo -ne '\e[5 q'

    # Use beam shape cursor for each new prompt.
    preexec() {
       echo -ne '\e[5 q'
    }
```

As found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/327572).

In `vim`, I use *[Vundle](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim)* and *[terminus](https://github.com/wincent/terminus)*.

With these configurations, both `zsh` and `vim` work as they should when considered independently. 
However, when I enter `vim` from `zsh` in *insert mode*, `vim` starts in *normal mode* (as it should) but still shows the beam shape cursor.
Similarly, when I exit `vim`, I get back to `zsh` in *insert mode*, but the cursor is still in block shape (since the last mode in `vim` was *normal*).

When after this, I switch modes for the first time (in both `zsh` and `vim`), the cursor behaves the way it should again.

How can I make them display the correct cursor after entering and exiting `vim` as well?

I tried putting

```
    autocmd VimEnter * stopinsert
    autocmd VimLeave * startinsert
```

in my `~.vimrc`, but this does not affect the cursor.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think it's better to use `precmd()` instead of `preexec()`:

```
# .zshrc

_fix_cursor() {
   echo -ne '\e[5 q'
}

precmd_functions+=(_fix_cursor)
```

This way:

- you don't have to change `.vimrc`
- cursor is fixed also when you create a new prompt without executing a command
- you don't have to write `echo -ne '\e[5 q'` twice in your `.zshrc`.

Comment: yes, this is nicer and works pretty well. Thanks! :)

Comment: @maddingl Maybe you should consider changing the accepted answer to this one instead :)

Comment: I use `zle-line-finish() { echo -ne "\e[2 q" }` and it's working as well.

Comment: But this doesn't change back to a block when going into normal mode

Answer (score 12):

This works perfectly for me, it's taken from here: https://gist.github.com/LukeSmithxyz/e62f26e55ea8b0ed41a65912fbebbe52

```bsh
# vi mode
bindkey -v
export KEYTIMEOUT=1

# Change cursor shape for different vi modes.
function zle-keymap-select {
  if [[ ${KEYMAP} == vicmd ]] ||
     [[ $1 = 'block' ]]; then
    echo -ne '\e[1 q'
  elif [[ ${KEYMAP} == main ]] ||
       [[ ${KEYMAP} == viins ]] ||
       [[ ${KEYMAP} = '' ]] ||
       [[ $1 = 'beam' ]]; then
    echo -ne '\e[5 q'
  fi
}
zle -N zle-keymap-select
zle-line-init() {
    zle -K viins # initiate `vi insert` as keymap (can be removed if `bindkey -V` has been set elsewhere)
    echo -ne "\e[5 q"
}
zle -N zle-line-init
echo -ne '\e[5 q' # Use beam shape cursor on startup.
preexec() { echo -ne '\e[5 q' ;} # Use beam shape cursor for each new prompt.
```

You can customise the type of cursor you want (blinking or not, |, rectangle or _) by changing the numbers in the following sequences `\e[5 q` (5 is for beam, 1 is for block) as follows:

```
Set cursor style (DECSCUSR), VT520.
0  ⇒  blinking block.
1  ⇒  blinking block (default).
2  ⇒  steady block.
3  ⇒  blinking underline.
4  ⇒  steady underline.
5  ⇒  blinking bar, xterm.
6  ⇒  steady bar, xterm.
```

Comment: Works like a charm. For those who want to extend this feature to interactive shell (e.g. python, scheme), you might find this helpful (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/409587/459602)

Comment: This works well, except that I cannot search for history using ctrl+R

Comment: @HungVo Ctrl+R is an emacs key binding. As soon as you set zsh to use vi key bindings, you need to have another short cut. The best is to use this `bindkey -M vicmd '?' history-incremental-search-backward` then when in command mode you can search backward like in vi with the `?` key. You can use `/` instead if it makes more sens to you.

Answer (score 3):

Simply add the line:

```bsh
export VI_MODE_SET_CURSOR=true
```

to your `~/.zshrc`.
It is mentioned in the discussion of [issue #9570](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/issues/9570).

Comment: This only works if you are using ohmyzsh.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution:

I put this in my `~/.vimrc`:

```
autocmd VimEnter * silent exec "! echo -ne '\e[1 q'"
autocmd VimLeave * silent exec "! echo -ne '\e[5 q'"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `zle-line-init()`

```bsh
zle-line-init() {
    zle -K viins # initiate `vi insert` as keymap (can be removed if `bindkey -V` has been set elsewhere)
    echo -ne "\e[5 q"
}
```

I think this problem is better solved using this, rather than `precmd()` or `preexec()` as both are intended to be used to execute commands, instead of fixing prompt.

Answer (score 0):

The following script works for me. It changes the cursor every time after starting/exiting a program.

```
function _set_cursor() {
    if [[ $TMUX = '' ]]; then
      echo -ne $1
    else
      echo -ne "\ePtmux;\e\e$1\e\\"
    fi
}

# Remove mode switching delay.
KEYTIMEOUT=5

function _set_block_cursor() { _set_cursor '\e[2 q' }
function _set_beam_cursor() { _set_cursor '\e[0 q' }

function zle-keymap-select {
  if [[ ${KEYMAP} == vicmd ]] || [[ $1 = 'block' ]]; then
      _set_block_cursor
  else
      _set_beam_cursor
  fi
}
zle -N zle-keymap-select
# ensure beam cursor when starting new terminal
precmd_functions+=(_set_beam_cursor) #
# ensure insert mode and beam cursor when exiting vim
zle-line-init() { zle -K viins; _set_beam_cursor }
zle-line-finish() { _set_block_cursor }
zle -N zle-line-finish
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I do it:

```bash
setopt vi
KEYTIMEOUT=1
# change cursor shape in vi mode
zle-keymap-select () {
    if [[ $KEYMAP == vicmd ]]; then
        # the command mode for vi
        echo -ne "\e[2 q"
    else
        # the insert mode for vi
        echo -ne "\e[5 q"
    fi
}
precmd_functions+=(zle-keymap-select)
zle -N zle-keymap-select
```